# Check if access token is valid - Identity Server

Tags: c#, openid, identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am using **Identity Server4** for a proof of concept project.I have implemented the identity server and I can receive an access token when I authenticate successfully.

For authentication I use, the following endpoint:

```
http://identity-vm-01/connect/token
```

and the details I post are:
[image]

Now, I would like to check if the token that I receive is valid. For that I am using the following endpoint.

```
http://identity-vm-01/connect/introspect
```

with a basic auth header using the client_id and client_secret as shown above, and pass token in the body.

But I receive an Unauthorized error. 401 . It will be great if someone could tell me what is that I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a scope secret for `api1` (on the Scope class) and use the scope name and secret as client_id/secret.

Clients for the introspection endpoint are not really clients in the OAuth 2 sense  - they are APIs.